# Automatically adding a user to a Parse class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a Parse class called Group which consists of currently enrolled users. In the long run, I'll be adding "default" groups into this class and I want each user of my app to be a member of these groups by default.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a background job to copy user to groups table, you can do this by adding a cloud code, visit this [link](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-advanced-background-jobs) for more details.